# How to resolve the hardcoding when a newer version of the library i use uses a different function name? - python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, duck-typing

**Is there a better way to resolve the problem of hardcoding compatiable code when a library i use uses a different name of the function?**

Also, **I cannot change the library code.** (because that function i'm using is EVERYWHERE in the old version of the code). The library is BeautifulSoup 3 and 4. see `Method Name` section in  http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Originally, i have bs4 code, but my users have bs3, so i have to put the following code everywhere:

```
try:
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
except:
  from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = '''<html>foo bar<p>blah blah black sheep</p> bar</html>'''

try:
  p = bs(page).find_all('p')
except: # Imagine i have to do this all over my code that uses `find_all` or `findAll`
  p = bs(page).findAll('p')
```

Comment: Why are you using version 4 when your users have version 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should just monkey-patch the bs:

```
try:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
except:
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

bs.find_all = getattr(bs, 'find_all', False) or getattr(bs, 'findAll')
```

Comment: ``bs.find_all = getattr(bs, 'find_all',False) or getattr(bs, 'findAll')`` might work better

Comment: okay, the find_all() with the old BeautifulSoup is still getting None when it's suppose to get something when using bs4